# Undo a Digest Cycle in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, undo-redo, angularjs-digest

I am working on an application (its a tool). One of the core requirement is to have support for undo-redo. I want ideas to start with the best approach possible.
One of the idea that came into my mind was to track a digest cycle and maintain all changes in each particular cycle which i can undo on undo button click (calling digest cycle again after undoing the change).

Changed Data sometimes can be large so performance is one of the things to consider. Need some real good solution.

Comment: Undo/redo functionality usually scopes on a form. You can set forms back to its 'pristine' state, which means it isn't touched.

Comment: In my case its not necessary that it will restrict to a form only. will setting it to 'Pristine' state change the input values to the original value too ?